# Animate Camera and OrbitControls to its default position in Three.js

Tags: three.js, tweenjs

I have a scene with Camera and OrbitControls in position. And I'm letting users to move around the scene and change camera view and OrbitControls position.

Now I have a reset button which will reset the scene view to its default position.

Answer (score 1):

We can do this using [TweenJS](https://createjs.com/tweenjs). Just include its JS library on your web page.

Save your Camera position and OrbitControls target position when its ready to display on web like this:

```
const default_camera_position = { ...camera.position };
const default_controls_target = { ...controls.target };
```

Now in clickListener of button use this code.

```
createjs.Ticker.setFPS(60);
createjs.Tween.get(camera.position)
    .to(default_camera_position, 500);
createjs.Tween.get(controls.target)
    .to(default_controls_target, 500);
```

And That's all.